# Duplicated path after refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I'm facing the issue with duplicated path. For testing purpose I made a TestingComponent to demonstrate.

My code:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'testing',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'testing',
    component: TestingComponent
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestingComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,

  ],
  providers: [DatePipe],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In app component html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet
```

The issue is specific for the project, when I made a new project everything works fine, but in this one:

When I enter localhost:4200 it redirects me to localhost:4200/testing (it is correct)
When I refresh page it is redirecting me from localhost:4200/testing to localhost:4200/testing/testing (which is strange and it should not work like this).

I have already tried changing order of the routes but it not helped at all.

Comment: Could you please make a reproduceable example on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: It hard to reproduce but the issue what I observed is I can type anything in address like "localhost:4200/whateever" and it will take me to "locahost:4200/whatever/testing" and display component.

Comment: Have you removed all other routes from your app and tested that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved. Someone added `baseHref` in `angular.json` architect build options. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This was the issue I was having in Angular 15. The above is what fixed it but instead of it being in `angular.json` is what in `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

You are navigating [relatively](https://angular.io/api/router/Route#redirectTo). Prefix the url with a `/` to navigate `absolutely`.

> A URL to redirect to when the path matches.
>
> Absolute if the URL begins with a slash (/), otherwise relative to the path URL. >Note that no further redirects are evaluated after an absolute redirect.
>
> When not present, router does not redirect.

```
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/testing',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
```

Comment: I added slash, but still the problem occurs, after refreshing my path looks like this: http://localhost:4200/testing/testing

Answer (score 0):

**It's working after adding  'pathMatch: 'full'',**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
  },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jnaiij?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.routing.ts

Comment: `pathMatch` is already in the routes.

Comment: you can follow the example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jnaiij?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.routing.ts

Comment: if your problem is not solved. you can show full code then i can solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue before.
For Windows IIS I had to change the entry

```
<base href="/">
```

in the initial *index.html* file or the project to:

```
<base href="">
```

later, when updating the project, the entry without the "/" slash caused the duplication of the URL routes in the development serving, due to the fact the root - "/" character was not present.

If you are facing similar issue, the solution may be by making sure, your *index.html* file contains:

```
<head>
    . . .
    <base href="/">
    . . .
```